# jQuery Combobox // Arrow Down issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm using the jQuery Combobox widget and I've got a problem using it.
When the focus is in it's Textinput and I press Arrow-Down it shows me
the results (filtered, based on the Textinputs value I assume).

But I don't want that in any case. For instance, if the User is tabbing around in an UI where there is already an item preselected in the combobox, he expects to see the whole resultlist when he presses the Arrow-Down key in the combobox's input.

I already tried overriding the _createAutocomplete method and add a keystroke handler like this

```
this.input.on("keydown", function (e) {
if (e.keycode == 40) {//arrow down
  //displaying all results
  input.autocomplete("search", "");
}
```

..but it didn't work.

Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's  'keyCode' not 'keycode'.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>


  <script>
    $('select').on("keydown", function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 40) { //arrow down
        alert('test');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Indeed I falsely wrote keycode. Event gets triggered now.